# Disconnect specific USB port in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, notifications

I would like to disable the USB port located at `Port_#0001.Hub_#0004` on my laptop running Windows 7.

I believe a USB port became faulty when I spilled a cup of juice on my computer, but I'm not sure which physical port it is (as they all seem to work; maybe it's an internal USB port). Since then, I've been occasionally spammed by notifications indicating that a USB device is not recognized, despite having no USB devices connected.  These notifications sometimes occur every few seconds for minutes at a time.

[image]

What I've tried:

- Disable the USB port via Device Manager. Result: No change.
- Uninstall the unknown device via Device Manager. Result: No change.
- Set the tray icon to "hide icon and notifications" via the notification manager to stop the notifications from showing. Result: the setting resets to the default "show notifications only" each time.
- Turn off the Diagnostic Policy Service, which supposedly creates these notifications. Result: Stopping the service didn't seem to make a difference, but I didn't reboot my system after doing so.  Regardless, I don't believe I should shut off the entire service just to stop these notifications.
- Turn off all USB ports by setting the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor\Start` registry value to `4` or via BIOS.  However, this shuts off *all* USB ports, which is not what I'm looking to do.

I've spent several hours trying to solve this now, so I'm asking here.

**How can I disconnect a specific USB port in Windows 7?**

Comment: You'll have to shut off the entire USB hub that port is attached to (in the Device Manager, and/or in the BIOS), and even that may not be enough.  But really, you have a hardware issue -- Get your hardware fixed. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you comfortable going inside a notebook and using a soldering iron? If so, continue on... If not, take to a repair shop.

You'll need to rip apart the laptop, to the point you have full, unrestricted access to the motherboard (or daughterboard) with the USB port. You'll need to unsolder the USB port CAREFULLY, and ensure none of the solder points are touching each other (otherwise you'll have a short, and never get rid of the message). This is a very delicate project, so let me just add:

### DO NOT ATTEMPT IF YOU DO NOT FEEL COMFORTABLE INSIDE A NOTEBOOK WITH A SOLDERING IRON! YOU WILL VOID YOUR WARRANTY

As an alternative as well, you can try to find a spare USB port from a notebook or attached to the outer case of a desktop PC, and attach that USB port to the notebook. The standard is the same, with power on the outside wires, and data on the inner wires. See the diagram for more advanced information:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll likely be taking it to a repair shop as I'm not sure which physical port is actually the faulty one.  Earlier, a specific physical port was malfunctioning when I plugged a USB mouse into it, but it's oddly working now.  I also just realized that, interestingly, I'm not spammed by these notifications when I have this USB mouse plugged in to any port; it doesn't seem to matter which port it's in.  Evidently I didn't do enough physical testing with actual USB devices, oops.